# Error HTTP Post Request Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: api, flutter, http, dart

I want to make a post request but suddenly it getting this error 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' is there something wrong with my post request because i been trying to make a post request.... Please can anybody help me fix this error that i been stuck with.

PostData.dart

```
class PostData extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future postData;
  const PostData({Key key, this.postData}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PostDataState createState() => _PostDataState(postData);
}

class _PostDataState extends State<PostData> {
  _PostDataState(this.postData);

  Future createPost(String url, {Map body}) async {
    return http.post(url, body: body).then((http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    });
  }

  final Future postData;

  static final cREATE_POST_URL =
      'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/HakimRahim46/mockjson/postData';

  final TextEditingController namalokasi = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController kodlokasi = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController nama = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController bodyController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Create Data Example'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent[700],
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
              title: TextField(
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Kod Lokasi:",
                ),
                controller: kodlokasi,
              ),
              leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.map), onPressed: () {})),
          ListTile(
            title: TextField(
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Nama Lokasi:"),
              controller: namalokasi,
            ),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map_rounded),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
              title: TextField(
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Nama Pegawai:",
                ),
                controller: nama,
              ),
              leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person), onPressed: () {})),
          SizedBox(
            height: 32,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              // ignore: missing_required_param
              Post newPost = new Post(
                id: 0,
                kodlokasi: kodlokasi.text,
                namalokasi: namalokasi.text,
                nama: nama.text,
              );
              Post p = await createPost(cREATE_POST_URL, body: newPost.toMap());
              print(p.kodlokasi);
              // insert();
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHeader()));
              // setState(() {
              //   print(kodlokasi.text);
              //   print(namalokasi.text);
              //   print(nama.text);
              // });
            },
            child: Text("Submit"),
          )
        ])));
  }
}
```

Postjson.dart

```
class Post {
  Post({
    @required this.kodlokasi,
    @required this.namalokasi,
    @required this.nama,
    @required this.catatan,
    @required this.status,
    @required this.id,
  });

  final String kodlokasi;
  final String namalokasi;
  final String nama;
  final String catatan;
  final String status;
  final int id;

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Post(
        kodlokasi: json["kodlokasi"],
        namalokasi: json["namalokasi"],
        nama: json["nama"],
        catatan: json["catatan"],
        status: json["status"],
        id: json["id"],
      );

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map();
    map['kodlokasi'] = kodlokasi;
    map['namalokasi'] = namalokasi;
    map['nama'] = nama;

    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are probably getting array from the api call. Can you print the response?

Comment: i get this when print response I/flutter (24900): Instance of 'Response'

Comment: `print(response.body);`

Comment: I/flutter (24900): [
I/flutter (24900):     {
I/flutter (24900):         "kodlokasi": "001",
I/flutter (24900):         "namalokasi":"Pulau Pinang",
I/flutter (24900):         "nama":"Ali",
I/flutter (24900):         "catatan": "Maklumat",
I/flutter (24900):         "status": "",
I/flutter (24900):         "id":"1"
I/flutter (24900):     }
I/flutter (24900): ]

Comment: Your result a List, not Map. That's why you are getting error.

Comment: you can use jsonDecode(). to parse the json result

Answer (score 0):

Your result is a `List`, not `Map`.

Try this. It will return `List<Post>`.

```
Future createPost(String url, {Map body}) async {
    return http.post(url, body: body).then((http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body)[0]);
    });
  }
```

Comment: it get this error  Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Post'